# Why didn't this field get added to to SOLine table

Tags: acumatica

I've created a simple DAC extension on SOLine in a customization project to add a string field.

I went through Code, +, New DAC Extension, and selected PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.  When I publish the code below, no errors are reported but the field is not added to the database.

```
namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
  public class SOLineExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.SOLine>
  {
    #region UsrABCD
    [PXDBString(10, InputMask=">CCCCCCCCCC")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="ABCD")]
    public virtual string UsrABCD { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrABCD : PX.Data.BQL.BqlString.Field<usrABCD> { }
    #endregion
  }
}
```

I'm not sure I can generate a simpler example so I'm wondering what I've missed.

I was able to add the field by going through Data Access, +, and selecting PX.Objects.SO.SOLine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add a new field to the the database. You first need to go to the database section of the customization project, and go to add > Custom Column To Table.

[image]

Then select the table you want to add the field to, in your case SOLine, the field name and its data type.

[image]

Once the customization project is published the new field will be added to DB. The next steps would be to create a DAC for the extension but that you already completed.

Comment: Makes, sense. To date, my customizations already had the database scripts in place and I haven't had to examine them.  Thanks!  I'll mark this as the answer as soon as SO allows me to.